# How to replace all "?" using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, replaceall

I want to replace all "?" to "%3F" but it doesn't work.
The Firebug console says: `"SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag %"`

My code:

```
var q;
var replacer = new RegExp("?", "%3F");
q = (document.getElementById("q").value).replace(replacer, "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor is a string containing the flags you'd like to apply to the expression. Use the global (`g`) flag to replace all instances. Also, `?` is a special character in regular expressions so you'd have to escape it with `\`.

Try this:

```
var replacer = new RegExp("\\?", "g");
q = (document.getElementById("q").value).replace(replacer, "%3F");
```

Or use a regex literal like this:

```
var replacer = /\?/g;
q = (document.getElementById("q").value).replace(replacer, "%3F");
```

You should also consider using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (or possibly [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)) method if you want to escape all special URI characters:

```
q = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("q").value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
"sample?".replace(/[?]/g,'%3F')
```

`new RegExp` Creates a regular expression using a string being the second parameter the modifiers `(g|i|m)`

If you want to use new RegExp then you need to do this instead `new RegExp("[?]", "g");` like this:

```
var rg = new RegExp("[?]", "g");
"sample?".replace(rg,'%3F');
```

Comment: Your code uses graves instead of quotes for `\`%3F\``.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are encoding data to be passed in a URL, so you probably actually want `encodeURIComponent`.

```
encodeURIComponent('?') //=> "%3F"
```

Which, of course, works for many other special characters as well.

```
encodeURIComponent('hello?foo#bar') //=> "hello%3Ffoo%23bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var find = "\\?";
var replacer = new RegExp(find, 'g');

q = (document.getElementById("q").value).replace(replacer, "%3F");
```

Eidt: forgot the "\\" infront of the "?"

Comment: That was my bad I forgot the "\\"

Answer (score 0):

```
var newelem = oldelem.split("?").join("%3F")
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var q = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("q").value);
```